JPA, removing parent cannot remove all children
I have a @OneToOne relation between Parent and Child tables , I need to delete all child if happen delete on parent because children doesn't have meaning without parent !
Parent Entity :
@Entity(name = "AcqPlan")
@Table(name = "ACQ_PLAN")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class IRIDE implements MpsIdEntity<Long>{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected HeaderType header;



protected Long id;



@OneToOne(mappedBy = "acqPlan", cascade = {
    CascadeType.ALL
})
public HeaderType getHeader() {
    return header;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the header property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link HeaderType }
 *     
 */
public void setHeader(HeaderType value) {
    this.header = value;
}

...

}
Child Entity :
@Entity(name = "Header")
@Table(name = "HEADER")
public class HeaderType implements MpsIdEntity<Long>{

protected Long id;


protected IRIDE acqPlan;

@OneToOne(optional=false, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {
    CascadeType.ALL
})
@JoinColumn(name = "AcqPLan_FK",nullable = false)
public IRIDE getAcqPlan() {
    return acqPlan;
}

public void setAcqPlan(IRIDE acqPlan) {
    this.acqPlan = acqPlan;
}

}
ok, the wuestion is simple :

why ORM doesn't create DDL OnDelete action ?
the main question , why if I run on DB "delete from acq_plan  where acq_plan.id =1;"
I got only the Parent ( acq_plan) record delete and not also header record related to it ?


Because you haven't told it to. Cascading operations will only operate within the confines of database updates executed via an entity managers methods to create, update and remove entities.
Hibernate does however offer a vendor specific extension to the JPA spec which should generate the DDL with the required on delate actions.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-cascade-on-delete

While the previous cascade types propagate entity state transitions,
the @OnDelete cascade is a DDL-level FK feature which allows you to
remove a child record whenever the parent row is deleted.
So, when annotating the @ManyToOne association with @OnDelete( action
= OnDeleteAction.CASCADE ), the automatic schema generator will apply the ON DELETE CASCADE SQL directive to the Foreign Key declaration, as
illustrated by the following

